# How to have shell script available to run in terminal and searchable in /bin?

Tags: linux, shell, bin

I downloaded CLion from Jetbrains, and it is a .tar.gz with a shell script to run it. I decided to put it in my /opt folder, but now I can't figure out how to run it from anywhere, *and* have it available in /bin (for programs like dmenu that search /bin for executables).

I tried adding the path to the script (e.g. /opt/clion/clion-2017.1.1/bin) to my $PATH in my .*rc file, but that didn't make it searchable in /bin? How can I have a single point of maintenance for something like this?

Comment: You can put a symbolic link in `/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need the executable to appear in `/bin` you can create a link:

```
ln -s /opt/path/to/script.sh /bin
```

Comment: That will create a symbolic link.  To create a link, omit the `-s`.

Comment: I ended up putting it in `/usr/bin` using `ln -s /opt/path/to/script.sh /usr/bin/clion` and now it can be started with `dmenu`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it *searcheable*, then you must copy or link it in some directory which is *searched* by other programs (like dmenu). But /bin is really not a good choice: the best would be /usr/local/bin.

Probably that other program (dmenu) can be configured to make it search in a few places, not only /bin and, maybe, /usr/bin.

About copying/moving/linking/symlinking, I would say that hard-linking is the worst option, because after that it is no more clear what file is the original one. But sometimes is fine. Symlinks are not bad if you want to keep separated distro things and your own things. But if you use /usr/local/xxx, that's automatic - nothing under /usr/local is ever touched by a distro automatic management. In that case, even moving the script is an option.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the directory not the file in PATH. So it would be:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/path/to/
```

Then from anywhere you can run `script.sh` and get it executed.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did do the directory and not the file. I made a mistake on my post. Edited.